# Yesod and Dropzone.js

Tags: haskell, yesod, dropzone.js

I have been trying to integrate dropzone.js with Yesod time and time again only to miserably fail.
Here is what I have

```
<form method=post action=@{HomeR} enctype=#{formEncType} class="dropzone">
^{formWidget}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

No matter what I do i just can't get the dropzone form box to upload the files which I have dropped in there. It just seems as if Yesod doesn't even "realize" I have added a dropzone class to the form.

Anyone care to help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't how to solve this exact problem.  However, it has a more general solution.

If you collect the request information (headers, POST body) for a bare file upload form and then for the Dropzone.js form you should see how Dropzone.js differs in it's preparation.

I suspect Dropzone.js is missing the anti-CSRF tokens that Yesod uses so Yesod is ignoring the request.  It may be possible to get deeper logging from Yesod at that level.

Comment: I know this isn't a complete answer.  Can you comment on the request/response differences with and without Dropzone.js?  It may provide a fast path for others to give you the real answer.